# Check if site uses custom Infopath forms and workflows using powershell

Tags: workflow, infopath, powershell

I have to scan my SharePoint environment to check how many of the sites have custom Infopath forms and Workflows (OOB or SPDesigner).

I am planning to use PowerShell to scan my sites/subsites.  Do you know how could i get the information on the Infopath and Workflows?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a PowerShell script for that exact purpose. It will output an excel file that contains all InfoPath Forms and Workflows within the specified Web Application.

```
# Find InfoPath Forms in the SharePoint Farm

Write-Host "Get InfoPath Forms and Workflows"

if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity https://webappurlhere.com
$outputObj = @() 

foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) {
        foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
                for($i = 0; $i -ne $web.lists.count; $i++) {
                        $list = $web.Lists[$i]
                        if ($list.BaseTemplate -eq "XMLForm" -and $list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
                                $FORM = New-Object PSObject
                                $FORM | Add-Member NoteProperty Type "Form" 
                                $FORM | Add-Member NoteProperty Site $($List.ParentWeb.Title)
                                $FORM | Add-Member NoteProperty URL $($List.ParentWeb.URL)
                                $FORM | Add-Member NoteProperty Title $($List.Title)
                                $outputObj += $FORM
                        }
                       foreach ($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
                       {
                              if ($wf.Enabled) {
                                  $WORKFLOW = New-Object PSObject 
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty Type "Workflow" 
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty Site $($List.ParentWeb.Title)
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty URL $($List.ParentWeb.URL)
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty Title $($List.Title)
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty WorkflowName $($wf.Name)
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty BaseTemplate $($wf.BaseTemplate)
                                  $WORKFLOW | Add-Member NoteProperty AssociationData $($wf.AssociationData)
                                  $outputObj += $WORKFLOW
                          }
                    }
            }
    }

}

$outputObj | Export-CSV -Path $scriptPath\InfoPathForms.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: To prevent memory leaks, don't forget to dispose of the `$web` and `$site` objects before the end of the foreach blocks in which they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

While this answer does great for finding InfoPath Forms based on Document Library types not so much for Lists with custom InfoPath Forms enabled, for this use this script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration parameters
$WebAppURL="https://intranet.crescent.com"
$ReportOutput="C:\InfoPath-ListForms.csv"
#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ResultColl = @()

#Get All Webs of the Web Application
$WebsColl = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All

#Iterate through each web
Foreach($Web in $WebsColl)
{
 #Get All Lists with InfoPath List Forms in use
 Foreach ($List in $web.Lists | Where {$_.ContentTypes[0].ResourceFolder.Properties["_ipfs_infopathenabled"]})
    {
            Write-Host "Found an InfoPath Form at: $($Web.URL), $($List.Title)"
            $Result = new-object PSObject
            $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Site URL" -Value $web.Url
            $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "List Name" -Value $List.Title
            $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "List URL" -Value "$($Web.Url)/$($List.RootFolder.Url)"
            $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Template" -Value $list.ContentTypes[0].ResourceFolder.Properties["_ipfs_solutionName"]
            $ResultColl += $Result
    }
}
#Export Results to a CSV File
$ResultColl | Export-csv $ReportOutput -notypeinformation
Write-Host "InfoPath Lists Forms Report has been Generated!" -f Green


#Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/find-all-infopath-list-forms-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html#ixzz5BdHWOyPs
```

As for workflows Dr. Quinn's answer works great, you will most likely need to run both scripts for a complete set of Forms and Workflows.

Happy SharePointing.

SG.

Comment: works like a charm! thanks for this answer!